# Radial node in p or d-orbital

Tags: orbitals

While studying atomic orbitals and nodes, the only illustration of a radial node that I could find is in an s-orbital (like [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/09._The_Hydrogen_Atom/Radial_Nodes#)). How do the radial nodes look like in p or d-orbitals?

(I don't know how to plot the distribution myself.)

Comment: A Google image search will provide many different depictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the following picture from [Chemistry Libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Saint_Marys_College_Notre_Dame_IN/CHEM_342%3A_Bio-inorganic_Chemistry/Readings/0%3A_Pre-Semester_Review_and_Introduction/0.1%3A_Orbitals%2C_Quantum_Numbers%2C_Electron_Configurations%2C_and_Trends/0.1.1%3A_Review_of_Orbital_Shapes). I don't own the picture, so the credit goes to respective authors.

[image: Orbital Nodes]

I believe the d orbitals illustrated on the diagram are only the $d_{z^2}$ orbitals. For the f orbital, I believe it is $f_{z^3}$. Please let me know of any problems/suggestions.